# unable to execute the block

Tags: sql, syntax-error, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

can you help me in rectifying the following code.

```
execute immediate $$
declare
    TABLE_CATALOG varchar default ('DB');
    TABLE_SCHEMA varchar default ('SCH');
    VIEW_NAME varchar default ('VIEW');
  VEW resultset default (SELECT * from table(GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES(DATABASE_NAME =>:TABLE_CATALOG , SCHEMA_NAME =>:TABLE_SCHEMA, OBJECT_NAME =>:VIEW_NAME)));
 begin
return table(VEW);
end;
$$
;
```

**The above code is written in classic web interface**

the following error appears when the above executed
`SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 21 unexpected ':'.`

when executed only the select statement  by replacing bind variables with respective parameters query executing without any hiccups.

```
SELECT * from table(GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES(DATABASE_NAME =>'DB' , SCHEMA_NAME =>'SCH', OBJECT_NAME =>'VIEW'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the [GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_object_references.html) does expect a string literal, your variables are already strings, as declared by `varchar default`. The error actually occurs, because the `VEW resultset` assignment requires a literal query as a parameter or a string ([when used](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets.html#assigning-a-query-to-a-declared-resultset) with `execute immediate`). You can achieve this by constructing the query first as shown below:

```
execute immediate $$
declare
    TABLE_CATALOG varchar default ('DB');
    TABLE_SCHEMA varchar default ('SCH');
    VIEW_NAME varchar default ('VIEW');
    QUERY varchar default  ('SELECT * from table(GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES(DATABASE_NAME =>'||:TABLE_CATALOG||', SCHEMA_NAME =>'||:TABLE_SCHEMA||', OBJECT_NAME =>'||:VIEW_NAME||'))');
    VEW resultset default (execute immediate QUERY);
begin
    return table(VEW);
end;
$$
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_object_references.html) the parameters should be string literals.

Non-parametrized version:

```
DECLARE
    TABLE_CATALOG varchar default ('DB');
    TABLE_SCHEMA  varchar default ('SCH');
    VIEW_NAME     varchar default ('View');
    VEW           resultset ;
    SQL           TEXT DEFAULT 'SELECT * FROM TABLE(GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES(
                                                    DATABASE_NAME=><DATABASE_NAME>,
                                                    SCHEMA_NAME=><SCHEMA_NAME>,
                                                    OBJECT_NAME=><OBJECT_NAME>))';
BEGIN
  -- checking if object exists(input validation)
 SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
 INTO TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, VIEW_NAME
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
 WHERE TABLE_CATALOG ILIKE :TABLE_CATALOG
   AND TABLE_SCHEMA ILIKE :TABLE_SCHEMA
   AND TABLE_NAME ILIKE :VIEW_NAME; 
   
 SQL := REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SQL
         ,'<DATABASE_NAME>', TABLE_CATALOG)
         ,'<SCHEMA_NAME>', TABLE_SCHEMA) 
         ,'<OBJECT_NAME>', VIEW_NAME);

 VEW := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :SQL);
 return table(VEW);
END;
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE DATABASE DB;
CREATE SCHEMA SCH;
CREATE TABLE Tab1(id INT);
CREATE  OR REPLACE VIEW View AS SELECT * FROM tab1;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Lukasz, since I am using classic web interface , when executed the above code I am getting the error.